# Material Table: Custom add button throwig error onclick in reactjs material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using material table in my project, and there is a scenario where all the row checkbox is selected true by default, and user can deselect if he wishes then move to next step in stepper.. Also i can add new row button in the current step. But when i have a check box selected then click on add, then it throw an error. Can anyone explain why. its happening.??

I am attaching codesandbox code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-add-mode-from-action-button-in-table-cell-forked-x5lb0?file=/src/App.js

[image]

```
<MaterialTable
        tableRef={tableRef}
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={tableData}
        title="Custom Add Mode"
        options={{
          search: false,
          selection: true,
          selectionProps: (rowData) => ({
            checked: true
          }),
          showTitle: false,
          toolbar: false,
          rowStyle: {
            fontSize: 12
          },

          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#F5F7FE",
            color: "#8C98A9",
            fontSize: "12px"
          },
          paging: false
        }}
        components={{
          Action: (props) => {
            //If isn't the add action
            if (
              typeof props.action === typeof Function ||
              props.action.tooltip !== "Add"
            ) {
              return <MTableAction {...props} />;
            } else {
              return <div ref={addActionRef} onClick={props.action.onClick} />;
            }
          }
        }}
        actions={[
          {
            icon: "save",
            tooltip: "Save User",
            onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
          }
        ]}
        editable={{
          onRowAdd: (newData) =>
            Promise.resolve(setTableData([...tableData, newData]))
        }}
      />
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => addActionRef.current.click()}>Add New</button>
      </div>
    </>
```

Comment: It looks like the div that the ref is attached to isn't(always) getting rendered. If it's not rendered, then `addActionRef.current` will be undefined and you'll get that error. You need to ensure an element with `ref={addActionRef}` is rendered before trying to access the ref's value

Comment: How to do that>?